# PHP Array Population Working on XAMPP but not Server

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xampp

Thanks a lot to anyone who can help me out! I've uploaded a gift-shop style website to a server running PHP v 5.4.19. The problem is that the image and page references that were fetched on xampp don't appear in the array on the server. Why is this and what is wrong with my code (apart from me not adopting msqli yet)?

```
        function smallDisplay()
        {

            $query = mysql_query($con, "SELECT `imageSrcQ`, `productCode` FROM `products` WHERE `displayCode` >= 11 && `displayCode` <= 12");

            while ($results_row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
            {

                $returned_results[] = array(
                                    'productCode' => $results_row['productCode'],
                                    'imageSrcQ' => $results_row['imageSrcQ']
                );

            }

            return $returned_results;

        }

        $results = smallDisplay();

        echo $results;



        $x = 0;

        foreach ($results as $result)
        {

            ${'img'.$x} = $result['imageSrcQ'];

            $x++;

        }
        echo $img0;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, "I wrote some code it doesn't work I have no idea why" is not a suitable question for this site.

Comment: anyway, most likely your question already has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** mysql_query does not take $con as the first argument, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php.

Change your code to:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `imageSrcQ`, `productCode` FROM `products` WHERE `displayCode` >= 11 && `displayCode` <= 12");
```

and it should work.

As a note you might want to declare your $returned_results - array before the loop, and use the mysql_fetch_assoc() instead